# Increase chunk size of Pyarrow FlightStreamReader

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

Is there a way to increase the chunk size of the `reader.read_chunk()` from pyarrow flight?  Where the `reader` is a `pyarrow._flight.FlightStreamReader` object from

```
reader = client.do_get(flight_info.endpoints[0].ticket, options)
```

Entire `example.py` script came from https://github.com/dremio-hub/arrow-flight-client-examples/blob/main/python/example.py

Currently each chunk is just `3968` rows.  Was wondering if I can increase this chunk size to potentially increase throughput from downloading the results through the network and also minimize the number of times the `read_chunk()` is called (especially when the total number of rows is quite large)